# Given any two quantum states and the information that the system is in one of these two states

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, measurement-problem, wavefunction-collapse

*Given any two quantum states and the information that the system is in one of these two states, one cannot reliably devise a single measurement which could determine with certainty which state the system is in.*   **Is this statement correct?**

I know that if the two states are orthogonal, one can reliably determine which state it is by one measurement, but I am confused about the above statement. It seems to be a little ambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

The statement is correct. Let's be really specific. Is there a way to, in one measurement, determine whether you have:
$$
| \psi_1 \rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \left( | 0 \rangle + | 1 \rangle \right)
$$
or
$$
| \psi_2 \rangle = | 1 \rangle
$$
?
You should probably suspect that this is not possible. Whatever measurement you would get on the $| \psi_2 \rangle$, you would also have some probability of getting from the first state. However, if you make a more complicated measurement than a simple projection onto a state (these more general measurements are called "POVMs"), you can come up with a procedure which might not give you any answer at all, but when it does give you an answer you can be sure that it is correct.

Comment: thank you. But if we are just allowed to use projection measurement, is the statement still correct?